# How do I get the value in my views? I am trying to use class based views

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to send a variable using class based views. Below is the code for the url file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myapp.views import foo

urlpatterns =  patterns('',
    (r'^/$', foo.as_views(template = 'home.html')),
    (r'^about/$', foo.as_views(template = 'about.html')),
)
```

How do I access this in the foo class in my views file? I am trying to do something like this:

```
return render(request, template_n)
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters you pass to `as_view` are assigned as instance variables on your class based view so you can can `self.template`, i.e:

```
...
return render(request, self.template, {...})
```

As a sidenote, if you were using a named url patterns that captured a slug, for example:

```
url(r'^about/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', foo.as_views(template='about.html')),
```

you would have access to the `slug` variable that is passed via the url by using the `kwargs` instance variable:

```
self.kwargs['slug']
```

Comment: Sorry, I know this should be easy. But I don't know why I cannot figure it out. 
This is what I am trying to do-
class foo():
 def template_loader(request):
  return render(request, template=self.template)

Comment: just do: `render(request, self.template)`